# Android dynamic features with DataBinding and R8

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-r8, dynamic-feature-module

I have problem with usage of DataBinding in my [Dynamic Feature module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery).

I can't generate binding object related for my fragment when `isMinifyEnabled = true`

Generally I try to do it using this code:
`val viewDataBinding: FragmentFeature1Binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)`
but value returned by `inflate()` is always null without any additional message. I tried to inflate layout using `FragmentFeature1Binding` directly, but I had the same results.

When I move my fragment into `app` module then everything is ok.

My app `build.gradle.kts`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.compileSdk)
    buildToolsVersion(AndroidVersions.buildTools)

    dataBinding.isEnabled = true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = ApplicationConfig.id
        minSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.minSdk)
        targetSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.targetSdk)
        versionCode = ReleaseVersions.versionCode
        versionName = ReleaseVersions.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName(BuildTypes.debug) {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            buildConfigField("Long", "API_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS", "30l")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dynamicFeatures = mutableSetOf(Modules.feature1)
}
```

My feature1 `build.gradle.kts`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.compileSdk)

    dataBinding.isEnabled = true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.minSdk)
        targetSdkVersion(AndroidVersions.targetSdk)
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        create(BuildTypes.instrumentation) {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.github.com/\"")
        }

        getByName(BuildTypes.debug) {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.github.com/\"")
        }

        getByName(BuildTypes.release) {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_ENDPOINT", "\"https://api.github.com/\"")
        }
    }
}
```

My `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }

-keep class kotlin.Metadata {
    *;
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
 -keep class **.R
 -keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

Without R8 everything is working correctly, so I am thinking some rule is missing but I tried few configurations and sadly there is no official configuration from Google.

Comment: Have you found the solution as per my answer?

Comment: @SanketVekariya not yet, downgrading data binding is not a great solution for my project :(

Comment: Do you have any update for this? I am seeing the same problem and trying to solve this currently.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( Recently I've updated to gradle plugin 4.0 and I'll try again

Comment: any updates on this matter? I have the same problem when I'm using Dynamic Feature.

Comment: did you include below code into your dynamic feature as well.                   dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

Comment: @GauravBansal Yes, I've added it in all modules

Comment: @PawełDedio Please make sure you are using android studio version 4.1+ and also if you are doing shrinkResources true in build.gradle, do that into gradle.properties as below. android.experimental.enableNewResourceShrinker=true

Comment: @PawełDedio have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem will occur if you are using android studio version 3.2 or above...
**Reason:**
from android studio version 3.2+, **"data-binding v2"** **is enabled as default..**
**Solution**
you have to enable data-binding v1 from gradle.properties like below

```
android.databinding.enable=true
```

It works for me...hope you will have the solution. :)